# python наследование, проектирование

Tags: python

У меня есть класс ChromeDriver для работы с вебдрайвером, который в конструкторе содержит его инициализацию. Есть еще класс SomeSite, который наследует класс ChromeDriver и все его методы для работы с движком, типа открытие ссылки + обработка возможной ошибки и тд. Объект класса SomeSite создается в цикле несколько раз, при этом происходит и инициализация самого вебдрайвера, т.е. создается много окон, что мне не нужно. То есть, я хочу создавать объекты класса SomeSite, чтобы при этом инициализация (ChromeDriver.**init**(self)) происходила только один раз.

```
class ChromeDriver:
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.__driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        except WebDriverException:
            pass

class SomeSite(ChromeDriver):
    def __init__(self):
        ChromeDriver.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Организуйте какой-нибудь флаг, что ChromeDriver уже инициализирован, и не дёргайте init второй раз. Например:

```
class SomeSite(ChromeDriver):
    initialised = False
    def __init__(self):
        if not SomeSite.initialised:
            SomeSite.initialised = True
            ChromeDriver.__init__(self)
```

Если не хотите явно указывать имя класса для доступа к статической переменной, то можно обратиться к ней как `self.__class__.initialised`.

Comment: как тогда можно получить объект webdriver, в случае если мы уже имеем инициализированный объект?

Comment: наверное тогда нужно сразу создать статический объект движка